# Remove class name from nodeList when clicked on any node from the same nodeList

Tags: javascript

i'm fairly new to javascript programming and i want to learn it more. I want to remove a class name from every node of a nodeList when i click on any node from the same nodeList.

I wrote this code:

```
d = document.querySelectorAll(".chat-line__message");
d.forEach(removeHighlight);

function removeHighlight(item){
  item.addEventListener("click", function(){
    item.forEach(function(element){
        element.classList.remove("highlight");
    });
    //for-loop instead of forEach doesn't work either.

  })

}
```

What am i doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: I did. My click event does not seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the `.highlight` class from every node in the nodeList, iterate over them in the `click` event handler and remove the `.highlight` class from there:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".chat-line__message");

elements.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
      element.classList.remove("highlight");
    });
  })
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li:hover {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.chat-line__message {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.chat-line__message.highlight {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="chat-line__message highlight">A</li>
  <li class="chat-line__message">B</li>
  <li class="chat-line__message highlight">C</li>
  <li class="chat-line__message">D</li>
  <li class="chat-line__message highlight">E</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're welcome @FurkanÖzdemir, please, mark my answer as accepted then. Keep up the good work and have a nice day onwards!

Answer (score 1):

`item` is a single element...the one you assign the click listener too.

You want to loop over the collection to remove the class from all the elements in the collection

```
function removeHighlight(item){
  item.addEventListener("click", function(){
    d.forEach(function(element){
  // ^^ iterate collection
        element.classList.remove("highlight");
    });       

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your doubt than you were almost there:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div class="myDIV">
This is a DIV element.
</div>
<div class="myDIV">
This is a DIV element.
</div>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
d = document.querySelectorAll(".myDIV");
d.forEach(removeHighlight);
}
function removeHighlight(item) {

   item.classList.toggle("highlight");
}
</script>
```

Have fun in javascript coding!

Comment: What is the purpose of " var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");" ?

Comment: Sorry Jeroen, that was from my test code. thank's for commenting (ok)